# laravel application can only share index page to facebook

Tags: php, laravel, metadata, facebook-sharer, addthis

I have an application on laravel and i am using AddThis (https://www.addthis.com/) for my website.

Everything is fine when i try to share the homepage, but i keep getting this "Whoops! There was an error." when i try to share any non-index pages.

I am using templating for the mata-data on the various pages

in my base.blade.php i have

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="ALLMENZ" />
<meta property="og:url" content="mycontent" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="" />    <!-- for facebook-insights-->

<meta property="og:title" content="{{{$meta_title}}}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{{{$meta_description}}}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{{{$meta_photo}}}" />
```

and in the non-index page i have

```
<?php View::share('meta_title', 'user timeline'); ?>
<?php View::share('meta_description', 'this is the user timeline page'); ?>
<?php View::share('meta_photo', ''); ?>
```

Anyone has any idea what is happening here? Thanks in advance (=

Comment: If you're passing in any queryString variables or UTM codes via AddThis sharer along with the og:url you may have to use the fix I explain [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23410463/1013405)

Answer (score 2):

You should generate the tag's content dynamically, for example, to generate the current `url` with `http/https` use following in your `og:url`:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ Request::url() }}" />
```

The `Request::url()` will generate the current `url` for the page you are on. Also, don't leave any blank `content` in any meta tag. Then debug the url's using [Debugger Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Answer (score 0):

## What Worked For Me

If you happen to be trying to use AddThis with UTM codes or other querystring variables, here's what finally worked for me.

As per [Sol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22852328/1013405), use  [OpenGraph meta tags](http://ogp.me/) but then use the [FB Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to verify that Facebook cache has been refreshed and got all the proper meta tags in the page header correctly, then verify that there are no querystring UTMs/variables your AddThis sharing link to facebook. For my purposes, Index.html couldn't include any querystring variables or AddThis passed the URL incorrectly to Facebook. The only way that worked for me looks like this:

```
<a href="http://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/facebook/offer?pco=tbx32nj-1.0&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Findex.html" target="_blank" ><img src="http://cache.addthiscdn.com/icons/v1/thumbs/32x32/facebook.png" border="0" alt="Facebook" /></a>
```

## What Failed For Me

When trying to use the below AddThis "data_track_addressbar" and "addthis_widget.js" modules for sharing, Facebook completely fail to pull the new OpenGraph Meta Tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":false};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js"></script>
```